# Subdominios para acceder a un directorio sin cambiar la URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo varios subdominios. Ejemplo:

```
company1.namesite.com
company2.namesite.com
company3.namesite.com
```

Estos subdominios accederán a un sistema que se encuentra en el siguiente directorio:

namesite.com/system/

¿Cómo consigo que los subdominios accedan y naveguen por el sistema sin cambiar la URL?

Intenté directamente a través de htaccess, pero no pude. Estoy usando un servidor Linux.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^company1.namesite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.company1.namesite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.namesite.com/system/$1?key=company1 [P,L]
```

Y en PHP:

```
$directory = $_REQUEST["key"];
if($directory != null){
   require "http://".$directory.".namesite.com.br/system/class/conectCass.php";

}else{
 require "conectClass.php"; 
}
```

Comment: Podrías hacerlo internamente, si el usuario del subdominio es el mismo del sitio, solo incluir los scripts PHP, pero tu sistema debe analizar la URL para tomar de ahí los datos necesarios y mostrar la información que corresponda.

Comment: Lo siento Triby. No conseguí entender. En mi caso, el objetivo es que el sistema esté en un directorio y subdirectorios para acceder a ese sistema en lugar de instalar el sistema en cada subdirectorio.

Answer (score 0):

Posible solución:

1. Crea los subdominios bajo el mismo usuario del dominio principal, con su carpeta en `/home/namesite/subdominio`, quedando la estructura más o menos así:

```
/home/namesite/public_html <-- Carpeta para https://www.namesite.com
/home/namesite/company1    <-- Carpeta para https://company1.namesite.com
```

2. Crea un archivo `index.php` para cada subdominio incluyendo el script del dominio principal:

```
<?php
include '/home/namesite/public_html/index.php';
```

3. En el script principal analiza el nombre del servidor [$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) para saber qué subdominio es el que se está mostrando:

```
<?php
// Dependiendo el origen de la petición puede devolver:
// - namesite.com
// - www.namesite.com
// - company1.namesite.com
// - www.company1.namesite.com
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
// Elimina www., nombre de dominio principal y posible punto del subdominio
$host = str_replace(['www.', '.namesite.com', 'namesite.com'], '', $host);
// Debe quedar solo el subdominio o cadena vacía
if($host == '') {
    // La petición es desde el dominio principal
} else {
    // La petición es desde un subdominio
    $company = $host;
}
```

Por cierto, es muy mala idea que se pueda acceder al mismo dominio o subdominio con y sin `www` a la vez, tanto el navegador como los motores de búsqueda considerarán que se trata de dos sitios distintos y, al final, te traerá más problemas que beneficios.

Comment: Gracias, Triby. Probé su código y funcionó parcialmente, porque cuando creo un enlace dentro del directorio principal, busca esa página dentro del subdominio y no en el dominio principal donde está el sistema.

Comment: @JM_2021, debes hacer correcciones a tu sistema para asignar directorio y URL de acuerdo al subdominio desde el que se está ejecutando.